# Why am I am not able to view data added to my excel using ng-csv?

Tags: angularjs

This is what my html looks like:

```
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs btn-block navigation-button" ng-csv="main.csvData"  lazy-load="true" filename="test.csv">Export as CSV</button>
```

And this is what the main.csvData contains:

```
[id: "1383817510", path: "https://amazonaws.com", A: 0, Bi: 0, Bri: 0]
```

Comment: Are you certain `ng-csv.min.js` has been included in your HTML file? Have you set the dependency like this example -> `javascript var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize', 'ngCsv'])`? Is `main.csvData` from `ng-csv` actually a directive to the element?

Comment: Yes for first two questions. main.csvData is an array as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

I know what I was doing wrong. I was setting an array in an array instead of an object.